# What is the correct way to read a binary file in chunks of a fixed size and store all of those chunks into a Vec?

Tags: file, rust, binary

I'm having trouble with opening a file. Most examples read files into a `String` or read the entire file into a `Vec`. What I need is to read a file into chunks of a fixed size and store those chunks into an array (`Vec`) of chunks.

For example, I have a file called `my_file` of exactly 64 KB size and I want to read it in chunks of 16KB so I would end up with an `Vec` of size 4 where each element is another `Vec` with size 16Kb (0x4000 bytes).

After reading the docs and checking other Stack Overflow answers, I was able to come with something like this:

```rust
let mut file = std::fs::File::open("my_file")?;
// ...calculate num_of_chunks 4 in this case
let list_of_chunks = Vec::new();

for chunk in 0..num_of_chunks {
    let mut data: [u8; 0x4000] = [0; 0x4000];
    file.read(&mut data[..])?;
    list_of_chunks.push(data.to_vec());
}
```

Although this seems to work fine, it looks a bit convoluted. I read:

- For each iteration, create a new array on stack
- Read the chunk into the array
- Copy the contents of the array into a new `Vec` and then **move** the `Vec` into the `list_of_chunks` `Vec`.

I'm not sure if it's idiomatic or even possible, but I'd rather have something like this:

- Create a `Vec` with `num_of_chunk` elements where each element is another `Vec` of size 16KB.
- Read file chunk directly into the correct `Vec`

No copying and we make sure memory is allocated before reading the file.

Is that approach possible? or is there a better conventional/idiomatic/correct way to do this?
I'm wondering if `Vec` is the correct type for solving this. I mean, I won't need the array to grow after reading the file.

Comment: Do you need all chunks in memory at the same time? If not, you could allocate a single buffer and reuse it in each iteration.

Comment: Why do you believe that having a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` will be better than a single `Vec<u8>`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I know it's not. I just want to be able to do something like `list_of_chunks[chunk_number][offset]` instead of calling a function which does the math: `buffer[chunk_number*size_of_chunks+offset]`. In the first approach once everything is loaded, I don't even need to use `size_of_chunks`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most idiomatic way would be to use an iterator. The code below (freely inspired by [M-ou-se's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55558173/155423)):

- Handles many use cases by using generic types
- Will use a pre-allocated vector
- Hides side effect
- Avoid copying data twice

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, Seek, SeekFrom};

struct Chunks<R> {
    read: R,
    size: usize,
    hint: (usize, Option<usize>),
}

impl<R> Chunks<R> {
    pub fn new(read: R, size: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            read,
            size,
            hint: (0, None),
        }
    }

    pub fn from_seek(mut read: R, size: usize) -> io::Result<Self>
    where
        R: Seek,
    {
        let old_pos = read.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))?;
        let len = read.seek(SeekFrom::End(0))?;

        let rest = (len - old_pos) as usize; // len is always >= old_pos but they are u64
        if rest != 0 {
            read.seek(SeekFrom::Start(old_pos))?;
        }

        let min = rest / size + if rest % size != 0 { 1 } else { 0 };
        Ok(Self {
            read,
            size,
            hint: (min, None), // this could be wrong I'm unsure
        })
    }

    // This could be useful if you want to try to recover from an error
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> R {
        self.read
    }
}

impl<R> Iterator for Chunks<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    type Item = io::Result<Vec<u8>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut chunk = Vec::with_capacity(self.size);
        match self
            .read
            .by_ref()
            .take(chunk.capacity() as u64)
            .read_to_end(&mut chunk)
        {
            Ok(n) => {
                if n != 0 {
                    Some(Ok(chunk))
                } else {
                    None
                }
            }
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        }
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.hint
    }
}

trait ReadPlus: Read {
    fn chunks(self, size: usize) -> Chunks<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Chunks::new(self, size)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> ReadPlus for T where T: Read {}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = std::fs::File::open("src/main.rs")?;
    let iter = Chunks::from_seek(file, 0xFF)?; // replace with anything 0xFF was to test

    println!("{:?}", iter.size_hint());
    // This iterator could return Err forever be careful collect it into an Result
    let chunks = iter.collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", chunks.len(), chunks.capacity());

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 26):

[`Read::read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end) reads efficiently directly into a `Vec`. If you want it in chunks, combine it with [`Read::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) to limit the amount of bytes that `read_to_end` will read.

Example:

```rust
let mut file = std::fs::File::open("your_file")?;

let mut list_of_chunks = Vec::new();

let chunk_size = 0x4000;

loop {
    let mut chunk = Vec::with_capacity(chunk_size);
    let n = file.by_ref().take(chunk_size as u64).read_to_end(&mut chunk)?;
    if n == 0 { break; }
    list_of_chunks.push(chunk);
    if n < chunk_size { break; }
}
```

The last `if` is not necessary, but it prevents an extra `read` call: If less than the requested amount of bytes was read by `read_to_end`, we can expect the next `read` to read nothing, since we hit the end of the file.

Comment: I was not aware of `Read::take`. Even if I'd seen it in the docs it would be hard to realize it's for limiting read_to_end. Anyway, that was just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @dospro Yeah, it wouldn't hurt if there was a `Read::read_n(&mut self, v: &mut Vec<u8>, n: usize)` that would call `.take(n).read_to_end(v)` for you. Right now this usage of `read_to_end` with `take` is hard to discover.