# How do I read chunk by chunk from a type that implements Read?

Tags: rust, io

I need to read data into chunks of an exact size (the last chunk may be partially filled). Ideally, this method would also work for all types that are `Read`. My initial idea was something along the lines of:

```
use std::io::{self, prelude::*};
use std::error;

const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 2;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    let mut a = &[1u8, 2, 3, 4, 5][..]; // Some Read type
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; CHUNK_SIZE];
    loop {
        match a.read_exact(&mut buf) {
            Ok(_) => println!("{:?}", buf),
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,
            Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
        }
    }
    buf.clear();
    a.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    println!("{:?}", buf);
    Ok(())
}
```

This toy example works; however, reading the [documentation for `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) I can't seem to reason if it is correct. The documentation says that after a failed `read_exact` nothing can be assumed about the buffer contents. Will the `read_to_end` after a failed `read_exact` always retrieve those remaining bytes?

Is this code correct or is there a better way to read chunks?

Comment: The important sentence is: "If this function returns an error, it is unspecified how many bytes it has read..." Your code assumes a failed `read_exact` read 0 bytes but that's not a reliable assumption.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the most efficient way to read a large file in chunks without loading the entire file in memory at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37079342/155423); [What is the correct way to read a binary file in chunks of a fixed size and store all of those chunks into a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563191/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure your chunked reads work, use `read`, not `read_exact`. `read` returns a `Result<usize>` with the number of bytes read, and `0` if it reaches an EOF. This will ensure that it works with partial data.

Comment: This is always a possibility, especially with a ChunkRead trait that's implemented for all Read or something. I was just hoping for something more idiomatic/built in given that `read_exactly` is so close to what I wanted.